# How can i change Slider Revolution with simple slider?

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

My theme has a Slider Revolution installed by default. Because of the problem with "Defer parsing of JavaScript" which I solved, I had to turn the slider off, well actually it just doesn't work anymore. That's why now I want to exchange this slider with the most simple changing pictures solution at that position.

So please tell me in what file should I look for the code and which code should be changed with what code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove slider revolution completely than deactivate slider revolution plugin and delete it. After delete slider revolution plugin you can use LayerSlider plugin for the slider.

Comment: if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer. @roman